# How to store the result of which postcode has the most occurrences of illness

Tags: r

How to store the result of which postcode has the most occurrences of illness? I create a table contain postcode and the occurrences of themselves.  But I don't know what to do next

[image]

this is the head 5 rows of dataset
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAyGv.png)

Comment: Could you please include a sample of your data using `dput(oswego_address_separate`. Please don’t use images of data as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. Questions should be reproducible. Check out stack overflow guidance: [reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

I made sample data `dummy`, `as.table(c(2,1,1,1,2,3))` which is like

```
A B C D E F 
2 1 1 1 2 3
```

Simply using `which.max()`, `which.max(dummy)` prints

```
F 
6
```

in your case, `which.max(ill2)` is what you want